# Can you define your own HTML element attributes?

Tags: jquery, html, syntax, attr

I was wondering if you can define your own attributes in HTML. For example in HTML divs there's a range of attributes, such as `style`, `title`, `class` etc. Can you make up and add your own, while remaining syntactically correct?

For example: `<div class="example" test_item="20"></div>`

The need for this is with regards to Javascript and data.

Comment: You can, it'll work, but it won't be correct HTML, except for HTML5's data attribute.

Comment: Is your question purely about HTML validation? Or is it about practical application?

Comment: I want to be able to use it, but i'd rather find a creative alternative to ensure it's properly validated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With one exception — no. HTML uses the attributes and elements defined by the specification, and only those attributes and elements.

That exception is attributes with [names starting `data-`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes), and then only if you are following the HTML 5 draft.

That said, it is often appropriate to encode the data in the `id` or `class` attribute.

Comment: Further to this, these attributes are automatically parsed into jQuery’s data collection. So for example, if you have: <div id="example" data-test="20"></div> then you can read it in jQuery with $('#example').data('test')

Comment: @patrick dw — namespace collisions, keeping HTML sane and on purpose (HTML 5 prefers cow paths over sanity), future proofing..

Comment: You sure can, however it wont be a W3C compliant HTML 4.01 document.

Comment: Quentin, I would rephrase it to say - You can, but then the HTML document won't be standards compliant.

Comment: If it isn't standards compliant then it isn't HTML, even if browsers can cope with it.

Comment: @Quentin: So what you actually mean is that you can, but you'd personally advise against it.

Comment: @Quentin: Then how is it that I can do `el.getAttribute('test_item')`?

Comment: @patrick dw — Because the browser is performing error recovery on your pseudo-HTML.

Comment: @Quentin: Error recovery meaning allowing features outside the spec?

Comment: @patrick dw — Error recovery means encountering something that should not be there and making best efforts not to break.

Comment: @Quentin: Does the spec specifically disallow custom attributes? I've never looked. If you're going to give an absolute "no" for a feature that otherwise works, it would be good to see some backing. The DOM spec didn't have `innerHTML` either, but I wouldn't say you *can't* use it.

Comment: @patrick dw — Yes (via DTDs which describe what elements may be children of other elements, and what attribute are allowed on each element).

Answer (score 3):

You can define the data attribute for any element as follows, and use jQuery data method to retrieve those attributes easily.

```
<div class="example" data-mydata="mydata")></div>

//In jquery to retrieve mydata you have to just say
$(".example").data("mydata");
```

Comment: This is great, is it only HTML5 compliant though?

Comment: Yes it is but for non support browsers jquery takes care of handling it in a different way. You dont have to bother.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically Correct -- NO; however, jQuery will read any attribute you add to an HTML tag without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

for the record you can add any attribute you want to an element with javascript using setAttribute("name","value")

```
document.body.setAttribute("name","value");
```

and it works fine.  This is also mostly cross browser: [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t1110)

Comment: The cross browser support you're referring to is for `setAttribute`, not the setting of invalid attributes.

Comment: @Ben Everard: actually I have tested it and it works (at the very least) in IE 8, FF 5, Chrome 12, and Opera 11 all able to return back the value of the set (invalid) attribute with getAttribute.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make my point very well, you're saying that `setAttribute` is supported cross browser, but the act of setting an invalid attribute that isn't defined in the spec is not supported, it just so happens to work because newer browsers attempt to recover HTML with errors in, take a look at Quinten and Patricks discussion at on the marked answer.