# jquery function to access hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

The code below is the general template for my music page.

The slideshow moves the song/image gallery forward or back sequentially, but alas, the '`switchFeature`' function, which should allow you to jump to various tunes listed in the sidebar, doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone point out where my error is, or what needs to be done to make it work?
Thanks!

```
<!-- music.php -->

<?php require 'header.php' ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".tuneslides").hide();
        var idName = ["#tune1", "#tune2"];
        var indexNum = 0;
        $(idName[0]).fadeIn(1000);

        $("#slidenext").click(function() {
            $(idName[indexNum]).fadeOut(300, function() {
                indexNum++; 
                if (indexNum > 1) {indexNum = 0;}
                $(idName[indexNum]).fadeIn(500);
            });
        });

        $("#slideback").click(function() {
            $(idName[indexNum]).fadeOut(300, function() {
                if (indexNum == 0) {indexNum = 1;}
                else {indexNum--;}  
                $(idName[indexNum]).fadeIn(500);
            });
        });

        // alas...
        function switchFeature (newIndexNum) {
            $(idName[indexNum]).fadeOut(300, function() {
                $(idName[newIndexNum]).fadeIn(500);
                indexNum = newIndexNum;
            });
        };

    });

    </script>


<div id="sidebar">

<h2>Featured Tunes<br>(click to show)</h2>

<p onclick="switchFeature(0)">Tune 1</p>
<p onclick="switchFeature(1)">Tune 2</p>

</div><!--sidebar-->    

<div id="main">

<div id="slideshow">

    <div id="slideback">Previous</div>
    <div id="slidenext">Next</div>

    <div class="tuneslides" id="tune1">
        <p class="tsTitles">Tune 1 </p>
        <audio controls>
            <source src="music/tune1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            <img src="images/image1.jpg"/>
        </audio>
    </div>

    <div class="tuneslides" id="tune2">
        <p class="tsTitles">Tune 2</p>
        <audio controls>
            <source src="music/tune2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            <img src="images/image2.jpg"/>
        </audio>
    </div>

</div> <!-- slideshow -->

</div><!--main-->

<?php require 'footer.php' ?>
```

Comment: What's actually happening that should be, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: You've obviously figured out how event handlers work, so why not use them and get rid of the inline js crap.

Comment: The slideshow successfully fades the audio/image in and out on click. The "switchFeature" function just isn't doing anything. Nothing happens when you click the words.

Comment: @adeneo - still learning my way around js here. Using the inline js was my way to pass parameters and keep the code light. If you have an alternate proposal, I'll try it.

Comment: Check my answer, it really is a scope problem in your case. However you should figure out how event handlers work. It's a blessing

Comment: will do thanks Hless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `switchFeature` within the scope of the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

Meaning `switchFeature` is in a different scope as the onclick event is trying to call.

Try to define your function like the following, and see if that works:

```
window.switchFeature = function(newIndexNum) {
   $(idName[indexNum]).fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(idName[newIndexNum]).fadeIn(500);
      indexNum = newIndexNum;
   });
 };
```

Comment: How does this make a difference?

Comment: Because attaching the function to the window puts it in a different scope as the document ready callback scope

Comment: The OP defined the function within a callback, then tries to call the function on an onclick event. The onclick event works with the global scope. The function, the way he defined it, is not global. The way I define it in my answer it is.

Comment: ALSO thanks for the explanation. Shows just where the relevant hole in my knowledge is.

Comment: Glad to help! I must add to this. While defining a global function this way is perfectly OK in JavaScript. It certainly is not a good programming practice. Try to dig into the jQuery event handlers for a more 'jquery-like' aproach. Docs for jquery click event: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite it a little so you don't have to do `onclicks` and you can keep everything together. Change the `onclicks` to use a class and html5 data:

```
<p class="tune" data-player="0">Tune 1</p>
<p class="tune" data-player="1">Tune 2</p>
```

Then convert that function switchFeature to a click for the tune class:

```
$('.tune').click(function() {
  var newIndexNum = $(this).attr('data-player');  
  $(idName[indexNum]).fadeOut(300, function() {
    $(idName[newIndexNum]).fadeIn(500);
    indexNum = newIndexNum;
  });
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/maxwbailey/pen/iKxCo

Comment: Nice, the more jQuery-like aproach is exactly this :)

Comment: question: what is the 'date-player' attribute? I have not found documentation for it. Did you just make that up, and if so, can you name a keyword that I can search on to explain how that works?

Comment: It is not an actual 'W3C approved' attribute. So in this case he created his own attribute only to access it later via jQuery.

Comment: like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899965/can-you-define-your-own-html-element-attributes ?

Comment: It's an HTML5 data attribute... you can read all about it here: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/